# Getting error in $.Get in SharePoint Framework

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, typescript

I have created following function in `webpart.ts` file to retrieve stock data from the Yahoo finance,

```
 protected demo():void{      
 var symbol='goog'; 
 var url = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=';
 var data = 'select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20("'+symbol+'")&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys';

  $.get(url+data, function(response  ){
        alert("Data: " + response );
    }); 
  }
```

By executing this url in browser it shows me data but with SharePoint workbench it gives me following error in console :

```
HelloWebArtWebPart.ts:77 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at HelloWebArtWebPart.demo (HelloWebArtWebPart.ts:77)
    at HelloWebArtWebPart.render (HelloWebArtWebPart.ts:69)
    at HelloWebArtWebPart.e._renderWithAccessibleTitle (workbench-assembly_en-us_ba5b10d….js:133)
    at workbench-assembly_en-us_ba5b10d….js:133
    at <anonymous>
```

am i missing anything in this snippet?i have properly imported jquery.

Comment: How have you have imported jquery ?

Comment: import $ from 'jquery';

Comment: can you try it as `import * as $ from 'jquery';` ? assuming that you have installed jquery as `npm install jquery`

Comment: That error gone by using `import * as $ from 'jquery';` but now m gettin g new error in console `Mixed Content: The page at 'sites/dev/_layouts/15/workbench.aspx' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.financ…%20symbol%20in%20(%22goog%22)&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS`

Comment: You are not allowed to call HTTP endpoints from an HTTPS server.. that WAS a serious security hole. So you have use the HTTPS endpoints (and most often you have to pay for those)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments:

You need to use it as:

`import * as $ from 'jquery';`

Regarding the mixed content blocking, you need to use the below url:

```
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20("goog")&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys
```

So, your code would be as below:

```
var symbol='goog'; 
var url = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=';
var data = 'select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20("'+symbol+'")&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys';
```

This is default browser behaviour. You need to change the endpoint to `https`.
You cant change this behaviour. Always ensure that you are pulling data over `https`. If its coming via `http`, browsers will block it.

[How to fix a website with blocked mixed content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content)

**Update** - so i had some time today, looks like some issue with Yahoo API.

You need to extract the XML and then get the value for the stock.

Below is a working code, modify it as per your need.

```
var symbol='goog'; 
var url = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=';
var data = 'select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20("'+symbol+'")&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys';

$.get(url + data).done(function (result) {
        //it gets me the entire page from which I need to extract xml
    console.log(result.documentElement.innerHTML); 

    var xml = result.documentElement.innerHTML,
          xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
          $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
          $title = $xml.find("Ask"); //use the element you want like  Currency,Bid,Bookvalue,DaysRange etc

          console.log($title.text());
});
```

Comment: I have changed the code as per above code lines now all errors gone but I am getting null data and it shows data in the browser while directly executing URL but it is not showing in web part.

Comment: i am using this snippet : `var url = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22goog%22)&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&format=xml";
$.getJSON(url, function (json) {
    alert(json);
});`

Comment: Check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13458132/json-formatted-stock-quote-api-live-or-historical , implement your code accordingly.

Comment: Check updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ditch jQuery and use the **native browser** Fetch API

```
  fetch(url+data).then(function(response  ){
        alert("Data: " + response );
    }); 
  }
```

You need a PolyFill for older IE versions, Edge supports it since v14

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

---

And it is best to use a wrapper function

```
function get(uri) {
    fetch(uri, {
        method: 'GET',
        credentials: 'same-origin',    // or credentials: 'include'         
        headers: new Headers({
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
        })
    }).then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            (data.d.results || [data.d]).forEach(item => {
                 ......
            });
        });
}
```